# How to setup Eclipse and Java JDK w/ Java-FX

Tags: eclipse, jdk, javafx

I'm really new to Ubuntu and I'm trying to get set up. I've tried installing Eclipse via the store application but that one seems really outdated.

Next I'm trying to install Java SDK and I'm really confused in how it works here on linux. What to use, where to get it and where to install it.

Help would be greatly appriciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to follow these steps. 
Download the Oracle JDK from [this page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html), if you have a 64-bit machine select the file *jdk-8u121-linux-x64.tar.gz*. Now open your terminal emulator and extract it (the downloaded file should be in `/home/your_username/Downloads`):

```
$ cd /home/your_username/Downloads/
$ tar -xvf jdk-8u121-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

Move the extracted folder in `/usr/lib`:

```
$ sudo mv jdk1.8.0_121 /usr/lib
```

Create a symbolic link to the `java` command:

```
$ sudo ln -sv /usr/lib/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java /usr/bin/java
```

To check the Java installation run the command

```
$ java -version
```

If it prints the Java version and others information then you have correctly installed it, you can proceed with the Eclipse installation. 
To install the latest Eclipse version you have to go to [this page](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/neon/3/eclipse-java-neon-3-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz) and download the archive file. Now these steps are similar to the previous:

```
$ cd /home/your_username/Downloads
$ tar -xvf eclipse-java-neon-3-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz
$ sudo mv eclipse /opt
$ sudo ln -sv /opt/eclipse/eclipse /usr/local/bin/eclipse
```

Now you can execute the command `eclipse` and Eclipse with Java will start.